# Delete all images in the selected range before inserting a new image

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to insert multiple images in selected range:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sPicture, PhotoCell() As Variant, pic As shape
Dim PictCell As Range
Dim fname As String
Dim I, x As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
    On Error Resume Next

PhotoCell() = Array("K6:P17", "A19:D29", "L19:P29", "A30:D40", "L30:P40", "A41:D51", "L41:P51")
sPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("Pictures (*.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png), *.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", 0, "Select Photo", "OK", True)

x = 0
If IsArray(sPicture) Then
    
    For I = LBound(sPicture) To UBound(sPicture)
        
        fname = sPicture(I)
        If I Mod 2 = 1 Then
            Set PictCell = ActiveSheet.Range(PhotoCell(x))
            x = x + 1
        Else
            Set PictCell = ActiveSheet.Range(PhotoCell(x))
            x = x + 1
        End If
        
        Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(fname, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)

        pic.Delete

        With pic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = PictCell.Height
            .Width = PictCell.Width
            .Top = PictCell.Top
            .Left = PictCell.Left
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set pic = Nothing
    Next I

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"

Else
          MsgBox "No Picture Selected"
End If
End Sub
```

however, I have lost all image objects when inserting this command

```
pic.Delete
```

so actually I want to replace the old image in the selected range with the new image and make sure that the old image is completely deleted.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you want to achieve: 
You first add a picture then you delete it in the next row ... this doesn't make sense to me. Furthermore: your `If I Mod 2 = 1 ` clause also doesn't make sense as the `else`-clause does exactly the same as the `If`-clause. Please *read* your code carefully - maybe then you understand the problem on your own.

Comment: ok i will check it again carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const PW As String = "123"
    Dim sPictures, sPic, PhotoCell() As Variant, pic As Shape
    Dim PictCell As Range
    Dim fname As String
    Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    
    PhotoCell() = Array("K6:P17", "A19:D29", "L19:P29", "A30:D40", "L30:P40", "A41:D51", "L41:P51")
    sPictures = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
       "Pictures (*.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png), *.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", 0, _
       "Select Photo", "OK", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    x = 0
    If IsArray(sPictures) Then
        ws.Unprotect PW
        For Each sPic In sPictures
            
            Set PictCell = ActiveSheet.Range(PhotoCell(x))
            x = x + 1
            RemovePicsInRange PictCell 'delete any existing shape in this range
            
            With ws.Shapes.AddPicture(sPic, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Height = PictCell.Height
                .Width = PictCell.Width
                .Top = PictCell.Top
                .Left = PictCell.Left
                .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            End With
            
        Next sPic
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=PW
    Else
        MsgBox "No Picture Selected"
    End If
End Sub

'Delete any shapes whose TopLeftCell intersects with range `rng`
Sub RemovePicsInRange(rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, allPics
    Set allPics = rng.Parent.Shapes
    For i = allPics.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Not Application.Intersect(allPics(i).TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Deleting shape at " & allPics(i).TopLeftCell.Address
            allPics(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks William, really helpful after more search or spend time.  I added a small method to reduce the file size after closing the worksheet, where all objects in "PictCell" will be deleted automatically before closing the workbook.
I added `PictCell.Value = sPic` before `"Next sPic"`

Comment: So how to convert url path to actual image with one click.

As a basic, I started with the code below (it doesn't work)

`Sub LoadPicture()
     Dim Tab1, Tab2, MyTab As Range
     Set Tab1 = Range("K6:P17, A19:D29, L19:P29, A30:D40, L30:P40, A41:D51, L41:P51")
     Set Tab2 = Range("K153:P164, A166:D176, L166:P176, A177:D187, L177:P187, A188:D198, L188:P198")
     Set MyTab = Union(Tab1, Tab2)
     MyTab.Select
     ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert MyTab.Value
End Sub`

Do you have a solution?

Comment: If you have a new question, then you should probably create a new post...